# How To Install Tap On AudioEngine OutputNode

Tags: ios, xcode, core-audio, avaudioengine, avaudiofile

I am trying to save processed audio from `AudioEngine` `OutputNode` To `AVAudioFile`.

Well Till Now What I Know Is That It Can Be Done Using Tap But Dont know how.

I Would Like To Know To How Install Tap On `AudioEngine` `OutputNode`.

Comment: It isn't at all difficult, and there's lots of example code out there. What's the hard part for you?

Comment: I tried it too but the tap was never called. It was called when I used mainMixerNode instead.